# django template syntax to iterate through two lists

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have the following django template, where as I'm iterating through a list (`class_list_overall`), I want to use `forloop.counter0` as an index in another list (`classTimeSlots`). It just keeps giving me a `TemplateSyntaxError`. I have tried the following variations:

1. `{{classTimeSlots.{{forloop.counter0}}}}`
2. `{{classTimeSlots.[forloop.counter0]}}`
3. `{{classTimeSlots.{forloop.counter0}}}`
4. `{{classTimeSlots.(forloop.counter0)}}`
5. `{{classTimeSlots.forloop.counter0}}`
6. `{% with forloop.counter0 as index%}
       <legend>{{ classTimeSlots.index}}</legend>
   {% endwith %}`

None of which worked. Any suggestions? I'm just a newbie at DJango. I'm using Google App Engine.

Here's the code snippet (I know it's inefficient but I've been trying different things):

```
{% for class_list in class_list_overall %}
    <fieldset> <legend>{{ classTimeSlots.forloop.counter0 }}</legend>
        <ul>
            <li> <label>First Choice </label>
                <select class="dropdown" name="class{{forloop.counter}}1" size="1">
                    <option value="Click Here to Choose" selected="selected">Click Here to Choose</option>
                    {% for class in class_list %}
                        <option>{{class}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <label>Second Choice </label>
                <select class="dropdown" name="class{{forloop.counter}}2" size="1">
                    <option value="Click Here to Choose" selected="selected">Click Here to Choose</option>
                    {% for class in class_list %}
                        <option>{{class}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't do that.

The template language will not try to determine the value of a variable passed in dot syntax.

It will do a literal lookup of `forloop.counter0`

1: write a template tag that accepts a variable and a key, and have it return the `variable[key]`

2: this can most likely be done in the view. Can I see it?

Comment: I finally switched to using a dictionary. A prototype is up on: http://acedautomation.appspot.com/register

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't support this - it's deliberately limited. Instead, you should modify your view function to `zip` the two lists together, and pass that in to the template.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It's a pity django's limited on purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but not recommendable:

```
{% for class_list in class_list_overall %}
<fieldset> <legend>
   {% for cts in classTimeSlots %}
    {% ifequal forloop.counter forloop.parentloop.counter %} {{cts}} 
    {% endifequal %} 
   {% endfor %} </legend>
    <ul>
        <li> <label>First Choice </label>
            <select class="dropdown" name="class{{forloop.counter}}1" size="1">
                <option value="Click Here to Choose" selected="selected">Click Here to Choose</option>
                {% for class in class_list %}
                    <option>{{class}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <label>Second Choice </label>
            <select class="dropdown" name="class{{forloop.counter}}2" size="1">
                <option value="Click Here to Choose" selected="selected">Click Here to Choose</option>
                {% for class in class_list %}
                    <option>{{class}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>{% endfor %}
```

But its better to take list into parent dict:

```
[class_list_overall[i].update({'label':classTimeSlots[i]}) for i in range(0,len(classTimeSlots))]
```

And then change above code to:

```
<legend>
   {{ class_list.label }}
</legend>
```